# Appendix Figure Placement

Tags: floats, subfloats, appendices

Sorry for the long message, I'm pretty new to LaTeX, only starting a few days ago to put my thesis together that's due in on Friday. I managed to get most things together but I'm having trouble with my floats for the appendix. My appendix is just a number of graphs.

Initially, I tried to output titles for the graph, and then the graph two to a page.  This code worked well until about maybe the third page, when one graph would be placed on its own, then it would return to two graphs per page again before randomly placing one float per page.

This is an example of the start of my code:

```
\textbf{Abutment Fragility Curves}

\textit{As-Built Pristine Integral Bridge}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{center}
  \leavevmode
  \includegraphics[width=5in, height=3in]{Model1Active0yrs.png}
  \caption[]{As-Built Pristine Active Abutment Fragility Curve}
  \label{figModel1Active0yrs}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{center}
  \leavevmode
  \includegraphics[width=5in, height=3in]{Model1Passive0yrs.png}
  \caption[]{As-Built Pristine Passive Abutment Fragility Curve}
  \label{figModel1Passive0yrs}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{center}
  \leavevmode
  \includegraphics[width=5in, height=3in]{Model1Transverse0yrs.png}
  \caption[]{As-Built Pristine Transverse Abutment Fragility Curve}
  \label{figModel1Transverse0yrs}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\textit{As-Built 50 Year Old Integral Bridge}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \begin{center}
  \leavevmode
  \includegraphics[width=5in, height=3in]{Model1Active50yrs.png}
  \caption[]{As-Built 50 Year Active Abutment Fragility Curve}
  \label{figModel1Active50yrs}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

To try to rectify this, I began using sub float.  With the first few pages, Using sub float I need to get three graphs on the same page as these are related and would require the same sub caption relationship.  However, despite scaling the sub captions are coming out on the bottom left of the graph with the (a) positioned below the graph and then shoving the figure out to the right rather than centring above the caption

```
\begin{figure}[]
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{Active Abutment}{\label{figModel1}\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Model1.png}}
  \captionsetup{position=bottom}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{Passive Abutment}{\label{figModel2}\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Model2.png}}
  \captionsetup{position=bottom}
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{Transverse Abutment}{\label{figModel3}\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Model3.png}}
  \captionsetup{position=bottom}
  \caption[]{Pristine Integral Bridge Abutment Fragility Curves}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

I need support in how to control a number of figures in an appendix!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I've just come across it! Sorry for that, thanks karlkoeller

Comment: @student1986: Please rewrite your code as a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) such that people, who like to help you, can do so.

Answer (score 3):

Since you just have a string of figures, I recommend making them NOT float.  Here would be a setup for a given page of two figures.  `\clearpage`...Rinse... repeat.

EDITED to show frame for verification, and to reflect on the fact that `\vfill` (hat tip John Kormylo) needs an anchor of some sort to push against, so as not to be absorbed against a page boundary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\null\vfill
\includegraphics[width=4.5in, height=3in]{Model1Active0yrs.png}
\captionof{figure}{As-Built Pristine Active Abutment Fragility Curve%
  \label{figModel1Active0yrs}}
\vfill
\includegraphics[width=4.5in, height=3in]{Model1Passive0yrs.png}
\captionof{figure}{As-Built Pristine Passive Abutment Fragility Curve%
  \label{figModel1Passive0yrs}}
\vfill\null
}
\end{document}
```

[image]