# How can I ensure a figure on an appendix page is constrained to a single page?

Tags: floats, appendices

I'm currently trying to develop my thesis using LaTeX (specifically through TeXstudio) and am having issues keeping a landscape figure on a single page in my appendix section.

```
\chapter{CHAPTER TITLE} \label{cha:AppendixB}
    \section*{DESCRIPTIVE TITLE}
        \begin{landscape}
            \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{Appendix2/IMGSOURCEHERE.png}
            \caption*{Adapted from \cite{CITATION1999}}
            \label{fig:IMGLABELHERE}
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
```

At the moment I'm getting my chapter title and section title on one page, and then the following page features the figure with the caption. Specifying the width and height doesn't help to keep the figure on the same page as the titles.

Have tried the solution given on [a question regarding appendix figure placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169088/appendix-figure-placement), but the desired outcome was not achieved (no error messages).

Many thanks!

Comment: the lansdscape environment does a `\clearpage` at start and end it can only contain complete pages, so you are forcing a page break after the heading

Comment: [Problems with landscape mode and Title on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118073/134144) and the suggested packages `rotating` or `hvfloat` might be interesting for you.